# Performance prediction on SQL Server and Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I asked already several questions on software design for DELPHI XE2 and ADO and SQL Server here. My application has to import data from a file into a SQL Server database and the code in principal goes like this

```
  type TRecordList = class(tobjectlist)
          .....
         end;

  var  RecordList : TRecordList; 

  for i:= 1 to NrOfFiles do
  begin

    Statusbar.simpletext := 'execute step #1 ';
    ImportRecordsFromFile(Filenames[i], RecordList);

    Statusbar.simpletext := 'execute step #2 ';
    ProcessRecords(RecordList);

    Statusbar.simpletext := 'execute step #3 ';
    WriteRecordsToDB(aAdoConnection, aADODatatable, RecordList);

  end;
```

Before changing this code to a multithreaded versions I would like to know if I can expect a positive impact on the total performance of my program? Is mutithreaded writing to the SQL Server database possible and faster or will this be the bottleneck of my approach?

Comment: It's possible and you could process multiple files at once, but possible DTS(X) might be a better solutions, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Why do you care about performance? Is it really running slow?

Comment: If Step 2 depends on the results of step 1 (as a whole), you'll hardly have better performance by doing it multi-threaded. If not, it really depends on a lot of variables, for example. Being general, you have to find first the bottleneck, when you know what the bottleneck is, you know if multi-threading is the way to make it fast, or not.

Comment: my idea :  create a thread for each  file  I need to tive import to the database; I check the execution with the task manager and from 8 cores of my system only 1 is active

Comment: what is "DTS(X) might be a better solutions" ?? never heard about it

Comment: @Franz former "Data Transformation Services" since SQLS2005 SSIS, but IIRC you are using SQLS2013 Express, which won't include SSIS, sorry.

Comment: I would not recommend going for multithreading solution. Instead, you could write records to database in one transaction.

Comment: @Franz http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707786(v=sql.105).aspx  but it is deprecated now

Comment: I would say that reading from a file is going to be WAY faster than inserting your data into SQL Server -- so you could be optimising the wrong bit.